How to pass date filter in sendgrid query param using java
I am using sendgrid v3/messages API to fetch the activity logs but I am unable to pass date filter in java queryparam.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sendgrid/api-reference/email-activity/filter-all-messages
sample code
                sendgridRequest.setMethod(Method.GET);
                sendgridRequest.setEndpoint("/messages");
                URLEncoder.encode(filterDate.toString(), "UTF-8");
                sendgridRequest.addQueryParam("query", "to_email='" + talentEmail + "' AND last_event_time>='2024-12-10T10:09:11Z'");
Response sendgridResponse = sg.api(sendgridRequest);

I am getting error as below.
sendgridPeriodicTalentDataDeletef4icne52knvv java.io.IOException: Request returned status Code 400Body:{"errors":[{"message":"operator \u003e= is incompatible with DATETIME, STRING","field":"query"}]} 

Please let me know how to pass filter like last_Event_time >= filterDate in query.
Thanks
Ragu
I am trying to pass query param in code to filter the datefield "last_Event_time" >= filterdate. but this is not supported in code.
Expectation: I need to pass the datetime filter in the code. please let me know how to achieve this.
